# How to prepare the data for Transformer model?

Tags: python, pytorch, transformer-model

this is Teddy. I'm considering training an transformer model using around 40 articles. I'm seeking guidance on how to prepare the data for this purpose. Just like I did for training a CNN with images, I'd like to know how to properly structure and p reprocess the text data for training the transformer model. Your assistance is greatly appreciated.
`

```
import torch
from torch import nn
import torchvision
from torchvision import transforms

train_transforms = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(size=(224,224)),
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    transforms.RandomRotation(10),
    transforms.TrivialAugmentWide(num_magnitude_bins=31),
    transforms.ToTensor(),

])

test_transforms = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(size=(224,224)),
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    transforms.RandomRotation(10),
    transforms.ToTensor(),

])
from torchvision import datasets

train_data = datasets.ImageFolder(
    root=train_dir,
    transform=train_transforms
)

test_data = datasets.ImageFolder(
    root=test_dir,
    transform=test_transforms
)
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

train_dataloader = DataLoader(
    dataset = train_data,
    batch_size = 28,
    num_workers = os.cpu_count(),
    shuffle=True
)

test_dataloader = DataLoader(
    dataset = test_data,
    batch_size=28,
    num_workers = os.cpu_count(),
    shuffle=False
)
```